# Why access_token is valid more than i expected

Tags: keycloak

I specified a token lifetime of 5 seconds in the keylock, but the token remains valid for 1 minute.

How to make the token have a certain lifetime and expire on time

[Keyclock settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqSel.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed session settings as well.

[image: Keycloak Session Setting]

Comment: I've added a user session limiter to the authorization flow that kills the old session, which means the session will be destroyed at that point, even though the token is still valid